# get request return 304 not modified if called right after delete

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tornado

i'm trying to test my rest api, however i've found a weird behaviour that if i create a get request right after the delete it will trigger a 304 and return the deleted object. I'm not quite sure why this is happening. if i wait a second with the get it will return a 200 code with where the object is deleted?

**Log**

```
2018-05-24 20:38:26,881 - tornado.access - INFO - 200 DELETE 
/api/v1/destinations/5b0706984db64f0b3ad92e13 (127.0.0.1) 0.73ms

2018-05-24 20:38:26,929 - tornado.access - INFO - 304 GET 
/api/v1/destinations (127.0.0.1) 39.74ms
```

**rest api**

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen



class Handler(base.BaseHandler):

    def _get_destination(self, destination_id):
        destination = self.datastore.get_destination(destination_id)
        if not destination:
            self.set_status(400)
            return {'error': 'Destination not found: %s' % destination_id}
        return destination


    def _get_destinations(self):
        destination = self.datastore.get_destinations()
        return destination

    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def get_destinations(self):
        return self._get_destinations()

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get_destinations_yield(self):
        """Wrapper for get_jobs in async mode."""
        return_json = yield self.get_destinations()
        self.finish(return_json)

    @tornado.web.removeslash
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        self.get_destinations_yield()


    def _delete_job(self, destination_id):
        destination = self._get_destination(destination_id)

        self.datastore.delete_destination(destination_id)


    @tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
    def delete_job(self, destination_id):
        self._delete_job(destination_id)

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def delete_job_yield(self, destination_id):
        yield self.delete_job(destination_id)

    @tornado.web.removeslash
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def delete(self, destination_id):
        self.delete_job_yield(destination_id)

        response = {
            'destination': destination_id}
        self.set_status(200)
        self.finish(response)
```

**pymongo functions**

```
def delete_destination(self, destination_id):

    collection = self.get_collection(settings.DEST_COLLECTIONNAME)

    collection.remove({"_id": ObjectId(destination_id)})

def get_destinations(self):
    rows = self.get_collection(settings.DEST_COLLECTIONNAME).find({})

    return_json = {
        'destinations': [self._build_destination(row) for row in rows]}

    return return_json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your _delete_job was spun off to be run while Tornado returned the 200. The _delete_job itself hadn't finished by the time you tried to get the same thing several milliseconds later

Comment: so is the solution within the rest api? or should i build some kind of timeout in the front end?

Comment: This is a common issue with async programming. Usually I see people try and fix it in the front end and just put a sleep or something. I don't know of a great answer otherwise